# Implement a heap unsing any arraylist

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist, heap

I am having problems on my insert method. When I go to add a number that needs to be swapped, I get an index out of bounds exception. here: Collections.swap(table, table.get(parent), table.get(child)); This is how I am adding to the heap. tHeap.insert(14); Thanks for any help.

```
    public class Heap {
private ArrayList<Integer> table;

public Heap() {
    table = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

public void insert(Integer toInsert) {
    table.add(toInsert);
    int child = table.size() - 1;
    int parent = (child - 1) / 2;
    //TextIO.putln("1  " + parent + " " + toInsert + " " + child);
    while (parent >= 0 && table.get(parent) > table.get(child)) {
        TextIO.putln("Swapping: " + parent + " Parent for Child: " + child);
        Collections.swap(table, table.get(parent), table.get(child));
    }

}

public void printTable() {
    for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {
        TextIO.putln("Index: " + i + " Data: " + table.get(i));

    }

}
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean `Collections.swap(table, parent, child);`? `ArrayList.get` will return the element at an index (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) `Collections.swap` swaps the elements at an index (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List,%20int,%20int%29).  You want to be passing in the indices, not the values at the indices.  Also I think in your while loop you may want to be updating `child` and `parent`.  I don't have eclipse on this computer to test anything out at the moment, though.

Comment: I cant believe I missed that. thanks

Comment: @WordsLikeJared Can you post that solution as an answer below so we can get this off the unanswered list?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `Collections.swap(table, parent, child);`? `ArrayList.get` will return the element at an index ([Java ArrayList API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29)) `Collections.swap` swaps the elements at an index ([Java Collections API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List,%20int,%20int%29)). You want to be passing in the indices, not the values at the indices. Also I think in your while loop you may want to be updating child and parent.